# Any objective VPS performance tools available?

Tags: amazon-ec2, vps, hosting, linode, saas

Because:

1. there are so many variables when it comes to VPS hosting (noisy neighbors, SSD/HD, host server specs, number of VPSes on host, etc...)
2. VPS hosts like to use fluffy specs (vCPU) to sell their products
3. Many virtualization platforms (Xen, Parallels, OpenVZ, VMWare, etc) have their own quirks and optimziations
4. Different server configurations and optmizations have extremely high impact on the server's capacity under different circumstances (ngnix vs apache, fast-cgi vs mod_php, etc)
5. Most hosts have burst allowance..

I was wondering if there is any way we can objectively compare VPS hosts to another on raw performance capability and/or if it would be possible to develop such a tool?

Comment: The *only* useful way to quantify this sort of thing is to deploy **your own application** to the system and to test it using **your expected load pattern**. There are far too many other variables involved to make a generalized performance monitoring tool useful for anything beyond just a simple back-of-the-napkin first pass.

Comment: ...which is why we have this canonical question and answer about [Capacity Planning](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning).